# Solve the halting problem for S combinatory logic

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, functional-programming, halting-problem, combinatory-logic

### Background

[Combinatory logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) is a system where a term is written using a finite set of combinators and function application between terms, and reduction rules are defined for each combinator. The well-known S and K combinators have the following reduction rules:

$$
\begin{aligned}
S\;x\;y\;z & \overset{S}{\implies} x\;z\;(y\;z) \\
K\;x\;y & \overset{K}{\implies} x
\end{aligned}
$$

A term is in *normal form* when no reduction is possible. A term has a normal form if a series of reductions applied to it gives a normal form. The halting problem in combinatory logic is essentially about determining whether a term has a normal form.

It is known that [any lambda calculus expression can be converted to an expression in SK combinatory logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Completeness_of_the_S-K_basis), and therefore the halting problem for SK combinatory logic is undecidable. However, neither K nor S alone has such property, and it turns out that the halting problem for each of them is decidable. But K is too trivial (it always terminates), so we turn to S.

A paper titled [The Combinator S](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540100928748/pdf?md5=d3887848b1976953801f88798b8dc834&pid=1-s2%20.0-S0890540100928748-main.pdf&_valck=1), by Johannes Waldmann, describes how to decide if a term in S combinatory logic has a normal form. Theorem 55 is the main result, and the regular tree grammar is also presented in Appendix 2.

### Examples

The expression \$S(SS)(SS)S\$ halts in two steps:

$$
\begin{aligned}
S(SS)(SS)S & \overset{S}{\implies} SSS(SSS) \\
& \overset{S}{\implies} S(SSS)(S(SSS)) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

But the two expressions \$S(SS)(SS)(S(SS)(SS))\$ and \$SSS(SSS)(SSS)\$ can be proven to be non-halting, as shown in the paper linked above.

### Challenge

Solve the halting problem for S combinatory logic.

In this system, a term is simply a binary tree where each leaf represents S and each internal node represents application. You may take the input using any suitable structure that can directly represent the term, such as

- a binary tree data type,
- a nested array,
- or a string representation using parentheses (e.g. `S(SS)(SS)(SS)` or `(((S(SS))(SS))(SS))`) or in prefix notation (e.g. `@@@S@SS@SS@SS`).

For output, you can choose to

1. output truthy/falsy using your language's convention (swapping is allowed), or
2. use two distinct, fixed values to represent true (affirmative) or false (negative) respectively.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. Shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 9):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>264</s> <s>260</s> <s>257</s> 235 bytes

```
⊞υθＦυＦ⊖ＬιＦι⊞υλＦ⮌υＦ⊖Ｌι⊞ι⍘§⁺§⪪”}∨M.⁶C¬²2´#±³¹⊗Ｉ↧β.|eBＴXmê�…⊟→⁼‹Ｒ$➙≧→↧ÀZLq);p↶⁷b⬤Jⅈ⁺7ς⧴Wn7bＺpïＸ|.➙Ｋ!μ…⁼@|v‹℅↨Ｓθ？mＹ,ＫＶ}⟧⎇Φ/◨7⁹¶↧πºwT～B0⁸!✳[➙↘↨cjf^{Ｍg‽bQⅉ→↥Za？↶⁶⊖J↘Ｄ⁻D⟲σ7r⬤？φ'⟦6f▷M↖¡[i⌊⊟\2ν｜¶x2;¹±＆~⁴K∨ρ‽↨⌕ＨMν(T‖β→⁵ⅈÞ↑«…i⊟Ｄ»”0⊟⊟ι×Cφ⊟⊟ιφ›³⁸⊟θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZRbT4MwFIDf9ysankqCCTovmD1RTYyJD8T5ZnxgrBso17bQcf48dihsbgW3k9DS7@vp5Tw0CH0WZH7cNF7JQ1xaqDBnk1XGEC5N1PaPNGA0oamgS/xC07UIcWSavzIyUZcYd4mvtKKMU7XAPyu0mZGFiM/pXLAoXWNXPKdLusFeXPJ@MM/jSGDjqxSJrCBy4gRkKSogTnyXAwAhQDgD4gKp7fV2/Df4svvTWtrba2hjTwL3R3ODUbvqbaixi95eujXsByEuc9TmbY59dWTrPXujOfP9iTcaP9X59z21zufXaj1qw96O12oKh@WAfFerz01VSAk55xykCkJYFgGBmnQJ9u1hNdXm8fC5kmGVnsnzAV4McDbAueKL41tIoaWlbg1ZaanU0o2OQq2loKWuHRJN2IaFDNswLeRlOd5@2zfFQm9RQjk2HpRemUdWodnEU0@NwE@M@oIyPHV@JhVqwqxp3tuwPyykml17iLTso7mo4m8) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a nested array where `S` is represented by `[0]` so e.g. `S(SS)` is represented by `[[[0], [[0], [0]]]]` (note that an extra set of `[]`s is required to input an array to Charcoal since it accepts an array of arguments). Explanation: Based on the look-up table on p. 16 of [http://www.cs.ru.nl/~henk/BEKW.pdf](http://www.cs.ru.nl/%7Ehenk/BEKW.pdf) but with the values translated to make the resulting table more compressible.

```
⊞υθＦυＦ⊖ＬιＦι⊞υλ
```

Perform a breadth-first traversal to collect all of the nodes.

```
Ｆ⮌υＦ⊖Ｌι
```

Loop through the non-leaf nodes in reverse order. This effectively produces a depth-first traversal.

```
⊞ι⍘§⁺§⪪”...”0⊟⊟ι×Cφ⊟⊟ιφ
```

Turn the node into a leaf by replacing its children with the value from the compressed lookup table.

```
›³⁸⊟θ
```

If the value is still less than `38` then the expression halts.

The following rearrangement of the table values is used as this places as many `38`s at the bottom of each column as possible. These are then discarded from the compressed string and reconstructed afterwards.

```
Rearranged  Original
         0   0
        20   1
        19   2
         3   3
         4   4
        16   5
        17   6
         7   7
         1   8
        18   9
         2  10
         9  11
         5  12
        10  13
        12  14
         8  15
        13  16
        14  17
        15  18
        21  19
         6  20
        11  21
        24  22
        23  23
        25  24
        28  25
        27  26
        22  27
        26  28
        35  29
        37  30
        32  31
        30  32
        33  33
        36  34
        34  35
        29  36
        31  37
        38  ∞
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 248 bytes

```
Œœżs2Œṙ$€}¥/F^Ị$;0xȷ¤s36
“ƙŀṂƒḂʂŻ⁷Ȧ¿ẏƑ<ọṭẹọ\Ṿ!µɗ⁻ȥƭĊƊġȯ;ŻxḂøCFO)1ɲŒṅ€+ṪʂU-Ɲ¿Ụ£þ^¶ ẹZ361PHc&ẓḟẉẹ⁴Ƒ@G⁶W6ṭ⁽A2K%Ṿ{ẉȯaỊ;ṆẊ:ḄtJ&ß>r³ɲȮ=Ŀ⁼ıɗt¦ÄɦñṙÇ⁹]ḷṡ⁸\]*<f6<U⁷ƲṬðẸG¬db⁾ƭɠ⁹S®w|XƈẎḤ⁴Ȯ⁺2BæƤḋ§Ḷọapæ4%ỊḞḟ¬v⁴ṇW^ŀ$ƈİƥX÷Ð{ṛƈ⁼T4\®ZṆ’b39ṣ0µṪ’s2;"Ç;€0
,ß€ŒḊ’$¿œị¢ʋ/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFbaxNBFH7Pr4iSFtSW5lICurF4gVb0QUFLa5sNtF4epA9iilaqsLtUExO8NHmoQWusTSLIJm2jTWZ2awIz2WE3/@LMH1lP0NKiDjOcy5z5zne@eXBvaemp7zsFp@gcpKNOAWgpJA3zOauOTabAzoWU8IrbZpV0LB6Q2kdRcjSghigAMfqGY0u97dZYF6y3Yj0B9mugdbAoOkmgnRNs39uQuu1WRb2XE7nelrujOPYKvuXk8uT1UxGvOej4AhueAfqtb0yPik1Esytsm3dSrBVEsLlYPHLjyp1hsIpAymC9wpzUf4j1C1NSb83EsaXUf16MXhvClqt47@4sIHEF6EuwcueArC1fHebliUfsu9d0G@d7Xakf9Pa8jWVW42teje/hzDwjdaoCaQPdkjpJqqcT9@OJaRxPNIGafBcsMsXMu4tS74i69xmrb7LGk2ezIgvWGyAVZOQ2pG5FL/GaqADJs69AWijEwkNeGx9CQkA@IX9mPsZSoJmZlKOFRLa3K6qzvM3frQL9ILJI7dZ4kjXmkL3USouxs0C3w2wf1cEwHVVO8oyCcoUDI7yMFuUjObwJsa5TBDvPvvTzY/5A1PcKfldwdCIotU2FZwI4oWHe9v35wHxkJDg4EfXI4vlv/t@c@qfy9z701GPuoADXEXLwWPB3hFiHgGpA/QU)

A full program that takes a single argument consisting of a list of S terms. S is represented by 1, and the parentheses are represented using nested lists. For example, \$S(SS)(SS)(S(SS)(SS))\$ becomes `[1, [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, [1, 1], [1, 1]]]`.

Returns 0 for inputs that do not halt and a positive integer (which is regarded as truthy by Jelly) for ones that halt.

This uses a rearranged version of [the table](http://www.cs.ru.nl/%7Ehenk/BEKW.pdf) found by @Neil for [his answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/229036/42248). Most of the work and the bytes were spent on optimally compressing this table from a 38 x 38 table of numbers from 1 to 38 down to 231 bytes. The code that actually solves the problem is a mere 13 bytes (not counting the newline that separates the two).

### Explanation

#### Helper link 1

Expand the run-length encoded segments and append lots of zeros before splitting into 36-length rows. Takes a single argument that alternates between integers to be used as is and run-length encoded runs of integers.

```
Œœ                          | Split into lists of the odd-indexed and even-indexed members of the original argument
          ¥/                | Reduce using the following:
  ż                         | - Zip with the following:
        €}                  |   - For each member of the right-hand argument (i.e. the even-indexed members of the original list):
   s2                       |     - Split into twos
     Œṙ                     |     - Run-length decode
            F               | Flatten
             ^Ị$            | Xor with whether the numbers are <=1 (effectively turns 1s to 0s)
                ;0xȷ¤       | Append 1000 zeros
                     s36    | Split into lists of length 36
                        ;€0 | Append 0 to each
```

#### Helper link 2

Niladic link that generates the look-up table to reduce a pair of S terms

```
“ƙ…Ṇ’               | Large integer
     b39            | Convert to base 39
        ṣ0          | Split at zeros
          µ         | Start a new monadic chain
           Ṫ        | Tail (which holds the first two cells for each row)
            ’       | Reduce by 1
             s2     | Split into twos
               ;"Ç  | Concatenate zipped to the result of calling helper link 2 on the other members of the list generated in the first part of this link
```

#### Main link

Takes an S expression as its argument and returns 0 for non-halting and a positive integer for halting.

```
           ʋ/ | Reduce using the following:
,             | - Pair
   ŒḊ’$¿      | - While depth >1:
 ß€           |   - Recursively call the current link for each member of the pair
        œị¢   | - Multidimensional index into the look-up table generated by helper link 2
```